# MS Dynamics CRM get Document Location

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-dynamics

In my MS Dynamics CRM 2016 Online integrated with Sharepoint I want to retrive information about path to record's file folder location in Sharepoint. Depending on it I need to display some information or not. Is there any concise way to just do it in JS? Or do I have to write a plugin and write this information somewhere in hidden field on the form? If so where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a plugin, and use the following information to retrieve the information you want to find:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309548(v=crm.8).aspx

Then, you can write the information on a field of the form (you can hide the field if you want, it's just a checkbox away).